# Position absolute jumps to the position while animating jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI scale to scale the images in, and in the animation chain, the chain works very well, I've one arrow image which is positioned `absolute` and assigned `top` and `right` property, but as the chain moves ahead, the image jumps instead of animating in that very place, I think it has something to do with `display: none;`, later, I will be having hundreds of `absolute` elements, I would appreciate if someone will explain me why this happens..

I am expecting the arrow image to load at the same place where it is showing up after jumping.. I want to scale in at the same place

Here's what I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".three_circular_img ul li:nth-of-type(1) img:nth-of-type(1)").show("scale", {percent: 100}, function(){
        $(".three_circular_img ul li:nth-of-type(2) img:nth-of-type(1)").show("scale", {percent: 100}, function(){
            $(".three_circular_img ul li:nth-of-type(3) img:nth-of-type(1)").show("scale", {percent: 100}, function(){
                $(".three_circular_img ul li:nth-of-type(1) img:nth-of-type(2)").show("scale", {percent: 100}, function(){

                }, 1000);
            }, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Relevant CSS

```
.three_circular_img ul li img:nth-of-type(2) {
    position: absolute;
    right: -80px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dq3tr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hide `li's` not `li img's` like,

**CSS**

```
.three_circular_img ul li {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
.three_circular_img ul li img {
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".three_circular_img ul li:nth-of-type(1)").show("scale", {
        percent: 100
    }, function () {
        $(".three_circular_img ul li:nth-of-type(2)").show("scale", {
            percent: 100
        }, function () {
            $(".three_circular_img ul li:nth-of-type(3) ").show("scale", {
                percent: 100
            }, function () {}, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dq3tr/1/)

**Updated** To show the `arrow` after all `demo images` try this,

**CSS**

```
.three_circular_img ul li img:nth-of-type(2) {
    position: absolute;
    right: -80px;
    top: 10px;
    display:none;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(".three_circular_img ul li:nth-of-type(1) img:eq(1) ").show(1000);
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dq3tr/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the arrow loads with the first image, whereas I animate the box images and than I place the arrow

Comment: Thanks a freaking lot, what you did there but?